# Search specific value in all field in oracle table

Tags: oracle11g

I want to search some keyword in table but I don't know to which column it is belonging to. I have got one of query for that as follows:

variable val varchar2(10)
 exec :val := 'KING'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR (:val, 1, 11) "Searchword",

```
 SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 14) "Table",
 SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 14) "Column"   FROM cols,
 TABLE (xmlsequence (dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype ('select '
 || column_name
 || ' from '
 || table_name
 || ' where upper('
 || column_name
 || ') like upper(''%'
 || :val
 || '%'')' ).extract ('ROWSET/ROW/*') ) ) t
```

ORDER BY "Table"

Searchword  Table          Column

---

KING        EMP            ENAME

but I am not getting appropriate output.I only got output as:
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. I have tried but I didn't get satisfactory answer. Can anybody please help..?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest query I can write for such scope is something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE UPPER(column1) LIKE UPPER('%' || :val || '%')
   OR UPPER(column2) LIKE UPPER('%' || :val || '%')
   OR UPPER(column3) LIKE UPPER('%' || :val || '%')
   OR UPPER(column4) LIKE UPPER('%' || :val || '%');
```

In this query I search for value `:val` in all columns of the table using OR conditions, so if at least one column contains the value the row is fetched

If you have many columns you can write a query that builds the final query for you, like the following:

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE ' || LISTAGG(column_name || ' LIKE ''%' || :val || '%''', ' OR ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name)
FROM dba_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = '<table>'
```

The result of this query is the query to execute. Note that Oracle has a limit of 4000 characters for a string field built in a query. If your where condition is too big the query will fail.

In this case, the only alternative is to write a stored procedure that builds the query and returns it in a CLOB variable, here's an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION build_query(in_table_name IN VARCHAR2, in_search IN VARCHAR2) RETURN `CLOB` IS

    lc_query CLOB := 'SELECT * FROM ' || in_table_name || ' WHERE 1=0';

BEGIN

    FOR c IN (
        SELECT *
        FROM user_tab_columns
        WHERE table_name = in_table_name
        ORDER BY column_name
    ) LOOP
        lc_query := lc_query || ' OR ' || c.column_name || ' LIKE ''%' || in_search || '%''';
    END LOOP;

    RETURN lc_query;

END;
```

This function will works and generates strings longer than 4000 characters.

Comment: whatever you have said is the right approach but I am working with the table having 290 columns 340 columns 150 columns etc.  so it would be difficult to specify number of columns in each query as number columns will vary from table to table..so..

Comment: I modified the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help friend but it's not working  and I am getting error as:
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.

Comment: Update again the answer. I hope this one will works as you need